# How can I create an empty table from android app in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing real-time application on Android platform and I want to add a table with specific name and no information at first in Firebase database. Is it possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

Firebase doesn't have the notion of 'tables' and there are no 'table names'

From the getting started guide from Firebase

[All Firebase database data is stored as JSON objects. There are no tables or records.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html)

So when developing your app it's important to understand the difference between NoSQL (JSON) databases and SQL.

Additionally, you can't really have a node in Firebase with no data.

So, you may want to re-think why you need a node with no information; as soon as you write information, the parent node will be created.

For example

define a user

```
public User(String name, String favFood) {
        this.name = name;
        this.favFood = favFood;
    }
```

write some data

```
Firebase userToAddRef = ref.child("users").child("user_0");
User aUser = new User("Harry Nilsson", "Lime Coconut");
userToAddRef(aUser);
```

This will create the parent 'users' node and add a child node 'user_0' that contains a single child 'Harry Nilsson' and his favorite food.

```
{
  "users": {
    "user_0": {
      "name": "Harry Nilsson",
      "favFood": "Lime Coconut"
    }
  }
}
```

If you really NEED to have a node with no data, maybe as a placeholder (?) is to write the node so the end JSON structure would be

```
{
  someNodeName: true
}
```

Comment: Thank you,I got it,But suppose that situation: I want to create JSON object with the name of conversation(User writes the name of conversation supposing in editText field), so when user goes to conversation and put some message, I want to put message in JSON object,too. But what information should I put when creating JSON object?

Comment: Easy! Using the example provided, the reference would be convToAddRef = ref.("conversations").child(conversationName) and then (assuming you created a conversation object),  convToAddRef(aConversationObject).  You should really take some time and go through the guide on the Firebase website - it will give you a much better understanding of working with Firebase.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll comment if I have a problem with that you wrote above.

Comment: Great. If it helps you, please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: I think ref is Firebase's object with my FIREBASE_URL,yeah? So, when I create another Firebase object called convToAddRef and write ref.("conversations").child(conversationName), It says it's an error because it's puzzled with ("conversations"). And I'm puzzled,too. Please,explain me what role does ("conversations") takes and what is it anymore. :D

Comment: After all, I think Parse is much easier.

Comment: The conversationName variable would be some kind of discreet name or number so you don't overwrite a prior conversation. So conversationName could be an auto-generated Firebase key using push() or childByAutoId. convToAddRef = ref.("conversations").child("0123")  and the next would be .child("4567") so each conversation would be stored in a separate child node within "conversations".

Comment: Oh - and to answer the question:  you had asked about storing the name of conversation as a JSON object.  users/conversations/0123/   and the next would be users/conversations/4567/ etc. Each conversation is stored as a JSON object within the conversations node.