# Firebase - How do I make a new table/structure?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am currently developing an API which gets data from Firebase and depending on that data the button changes its color. However, when I tried to make a new structure for my buttons. It won't let me make one.

I tried the answers here: [How to insert data of two tables in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031700/how-to-insert-data-of-two-tables-in-firebase) and here: [How can I create an empty table from android app in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480412/how-can-i-create-an-empty-table-from-android-app-in-firebase) but neither did work for me.

Here's my sample code:

```
public class Normal extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button suite, normal, room1;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase1;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

    //FIREBASE AUTH FIELDS

    DatabaseReference mSearchedLocationReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal);

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        //FIREBASE
        mFirebaseDatabase1 = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Rooms");
        mSearchedLocationReference = mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").child("RoomStatus");


        //ASSIGN ID's

        room1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room2);


        room1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Rooms").child("Room1").child("RoomStatus").setValue("Green");
                startActivity(new Intent(Normal.this, room2.class));
            }
        });


        mSearchedLocationReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //attach listener

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //something changed!
                for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String location = locationSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.d("Locations updated", "location: " + location); //log
                    if ( location.equals("Green")){
                        room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }else if ( location.equals("Red")){
                        room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                    }
                    else{
                        room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { //update UI here if error occurred.

            }
        });

    }
}
```

PS: I created the User structure (which is for my login) on another class.

[image: model]

Comment: Please add your database stucture.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should make a new structure at firebase you can do it by clicking the "+" beside your DB Name, here's an example:

[image]

Implement your methods and it should work. Then Connect again your firebase database.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when you are changing the value when (room 1) is clicked. You already declared this reference like this:

```
mFirebaseDatabase1 = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Rooms");
```

when you clicked the button (room 1) you triggered this reference to change value :

```
mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Rooms").child("Room1").child("RoomStatus").setValue("Green");
```

**In other words**

you are saying that you want to access

Rooms/Rooms/Room1/RoomStatus/Green

but you should be looking for this

Rooms/Room1/RoomStatus/Green

you have an extra child called Rooms that is repeated and causing the problem

**Possible Solution**

do this in the click listener of room 1

```
   room1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").child("RoomStatus").setValue("Green");
            startActivity(new Intent(Normal.this, room2.class));
        }
    });
```

I just removed the extra(.child("Rooms")).

Comment: I tried this  on my case but changes don't get saved on my database.

Answer (score 0):

What i think is going wrong is that an array is returning and its last item is green

```
for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
```

that is not letting you change the color of the button .

**we will be able to help you if you show the model of your database .**

Comment: Take a look at `mSearchedLocationReference = mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").child("RoomStatus");` I think it's listening on that node. That's if the table has been made but she said that it didn't happen.